# Does Gaphor Python package use standard SysML which can then later be exported for use on more advanced MBSE applications?

Tags: python, sysml

Gaphor is a python package which can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/gaphor/
More can be explained about Gaphor and MBSE here...https://gaphor.org/

Is Gaphor powerful enough to be easily applied in the early stages of a project and then scaled up using more sophisticated tools by extracting the SysML in a universal format and importing it to a more complex and advanced tool/ PLM?

Answer (score 1):

Gaphor has an exporter for XMI. It does, however, not export all elements at the moment, only classes, packages and such.

Gaphor's service architecture makes it easy to extend with your own modules, though.